Нужно ли тире в данном предложении
На первых страницах книги, рассказывая о своих путешествиях, главный герой произведения - Андрей Белорецкий описывает Беларусь и в географическом, и в историческом, и в социальном плане.

Возможны два варианта:
(1) На первых страницах книги, рассказывая о своих путешествиях, главный герой произведения Андрей Белорецкий описывает Беларусь и в географическом, и в историческом, и в социальном плане.
(2) На первых страницах книги, рассказывая о своих путешествиях, главный герой произведения, Андрей Белорецкий, описывает Беларусь и в географическом, и в историческом, и в социальном плане.
Пояснение
В первом варианте имя собственное никак не выделяется, а приложение имеет определительный характер. Во втором варианте имя героя является уточняющим членом предложения.
ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ
Вариант обособления двумя тире выглядит необоснованным для этого теста, а вариант с одним тире (второе тире опускается) подходит для простого неосложненного предложения, например:
Главный герой произведения — Андрей Белорецкий // описывает Беларусь и в географическом, и в историческом, и в социальном плане.
Здесь особая интонация, паузы перед именем практически нет, и такое тире можно условно назвать тире-дефисом. Этот вариант тоже не всегда уместен и применяется в особых случаях (образные выражения, значительная распространенность приложения).
Примеры можно посмотреть у Розенталя, пункт 10:
 Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается: 2) 
 если приложение выражает **конкретное значение**, а 
 предшествующее определяемое слово имеет **общее** или 
 образное значение: На совещании министров иностранных дел 
 стран — членов Организации американских государств // 
 выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы (Газ.) Прилетели сюда 
 первые ласточки — наши спортсмены // для участия в парусных 
 гонках;

